# What is the XSSAttack option_name for in the options table?

Tags: options

I am working on eliminating malware from a site and reviewed the entries in the options table. Found an "option_name" of XSSAttack with an "option_value" of 1.

Lots of searches on google and on the Wordpress.org site as well as others. Cannot find any information on this.

Is it something I should leave there, or is it something entered by malware?

Comment: That would be a pretty bold malware move.

Comment: I thought it probably was, so I have deleted it. Being new, however, I wanted to check whether it was something that is supposed to be there.

Comment: I'd guess that it's connected with a plugin.